Why do case_when() and if_else() appear to evaluate the wrong expression?
I am trying to process some messy date data from a .xlsx file. Some of the dates are pre-1900 because of typos during user entry. This results in Excel storing 1900 and onward dates as numbers and pre-1900 dates as exact strings. Because of this storage format problem, I'm using read_excel() to load the dates into R as character fields. I've tried using both case_when() and if_else() to convert the mixed formats into a single date-formatted field. if_else() works on my larger data set whereas case_when() coerces the pre-1900 dates to NAs. Both approaches produce warnings, but I don't understand why. Any insights?
The data look like this:
library(janitor)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(date=c("0982-12-27", "0996-01-01", "1201-02-10", 32874, 36526))

I tried two approaches before settling on the second one.
# produces desired output but warns about date-parsing failures
df <- df %>%
  mutate(date_new1=case_when(grepl("-", date) ~ ymd(date),
                            .default=excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(date))))
# Caused by warning: 2 failed to parse

# produces desired output but warns about coercion to NA for pre-1900 dates
df <- df %>%
  mutate(date_new2=if_else(grepl("-", date),
                          true=date,
                          false=as.character(excel_numeric_to_date(as.numeric(date))))) %>%
  mutate(date_new2=ymd(date_new2))
# Caused by warning: NAs introduced by coercion

df
  date       date_new1  date_new2 
  <chr>      <date>     <date>    
1 0982-12-27 0982-12-27 0982-12-27
2 0996-01-01 0996-01-01 0996-01-01
3 1201-02-10 1201-02-10 1201-02-10
4 32874      1990-01-01 1990-01-01
5 36526      2000-01-01 2000-01-01


If warnings are produced but your results are as expected, then it is fair to simply ignore the warnings. That being said, if you look up the excel_numeric_to_date documentation, it suggest using convert_to_date if you have a column with a mix of Excel numeric dates and actual dates. I tried it with your example and it works flawlessly: df %>% mutate(date_new3 = convert_to_date(date))

Wow, I can't believe I missed that in the documentation. This addressed all the cases in my larger data set perfectly. Thank you so much!

As Bastián mentioned in the comments on this question, there were a pair of functions in janitor that I completely overlooked.
library(janitor)
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(date=c("0982-12-27", "0996-01-01", "1201-02-10", 32874, 36526))
df <- df %>%
  mutate(date_new=convert_to_date(date))

convert_to_date() and convert_to_datetime() handled all the weird cases in my data without logging any warnings or errors - and in much less code than my solutions. Thank you, Bastián!

Glad to help! I also just learned about that function thanks to your question ☺️
